# Intel will soon be sponsoring Data Science

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that Intel will be sponsoring Data Science beginning November 11th through February 7, 2022. We wanted to give you a heads up and walk you through what it will look like.

## How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown in the top right header of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: Intelsponsorship]

## What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside
> our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the
> questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections
> as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a
> garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits
> still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has
> always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all
> Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for
> sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

## What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off please report it as a [bug](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug). so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns please leave them as answers below.

Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Data Science successful.

Answer (score 13):

Out of curiosity, I would like to know what kind of resources this sponsorship
is used for, and whether these resources are specifically spent on DataScienceSE or generally on the Stack Exchange network?

I hope that they offer brand new processors to DSSE contributors ;)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who doesn't like it there, its removable with uBlock Origin. Other cosmetic page surgery tools are available for those who need a clean uncluttered site with fewer distractions for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I also wonder how much sponsorship influences objective questions and answers. I readily admit that if constantly saw an Intel banner, as unobtrusive as it may seem, it might subliminally persuade me to throw "Intel" into a response :)

Comment: Note that this announcement is an old one from 2021 (this site sponsorship already ended); I simply edited it to add a tag.